# Get number of columns and column names from LinQ result set

Tags: linq-to-sql, ienumerator

I am creating a Grid view user control and I would like to know how to get the number of columns and the column names from the LinQ result set. This will be used to create a dynamic grid view.

What I have here is one class with this:

```
var myPerson = from persons in myLinQ.SamplePersons
               select persons;
```

And in my grid view, it has this property which receives the result set.

```
public IEnumerable<Object> SourceLinQ { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
var resultType =
    query.GetType() 
         .GetInterfaces()
         .Where(x => x.IsGenericType &&
                     x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
                         typeof(IEnumerable<>)
         )
         .Single()
         .GetGenericArguments()
         .Single();
```

Then:

```
var columns = resultType.GetProperties();
int numberOfColumns = columns.Length;
string[] columnNames = columns.Select(column => column.Name)
                              .ToArray();
```

This is untested, and I don't even know if it compiles (I don't have a compiler handy right now, sorry).

Comment: Hello! The first code is just an example of a result set to be passed. So, just for example, I have no idea on what is the query to be passed.

Comment: @Musikero: Did you read the code at all? It's completely general.